# How do I get network working on a Dell n5010?

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless, broadcom

Hey. I just formatted a Dell n5010 and installed Ubuntu 10.10. Now,when i try to access the Internet it doesn't find the available networks.

Informations about it:

- My network is set to broadcast SSID;
- Already typed `lspci`, and it doesnt returns my wireless card;
- Tried installing windows drivers from fabricant cd usind diswrapper, but it says it cant complete the installation because it cant find some "Device" folder;

I don't know what else to do, I switch the wireless button on/off and it just can't see any wireless connection, includin mine.

Here are the informations about `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated     Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI    Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced   Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root   Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced   Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller  (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI     Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you activate the restricted driver ? What does Administration > Additional Drivers show ? You seem to have broadcom card

Comment: the Additional Drivers show an alert box when start "Failed to Download their packages, please check the status of your network. Many drivers are not available". And then with the Additional Drives opened, it shows no drivers and its written "No proprietary drivers in use on the system".

Comment: go to synaptic and install bcmwl-kernel-source. try removing ndiswrapper if you are using it. If bcmwl doesnot work try b43-fwcutter or different b43-firmware-installer. It should work most probably. :) Follow this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: From Software Sources, enable all the repositories as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not connected to the internet, mount your Ubuntu CD or USB, and try to install from Additional Drivers or execute this command in the Terminal:

```
sudo jockey-text -a
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

The first command does the same thing as Additional Drivers, and should no return any output once it's completed successfully. The second command directly pulls the driver package for your Broadcom chipset. Following these steps with internet connection will work as well.